# Concatenate with VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

So what I'm trying to do is, I want to be able to press a button in Excel to concatenate multiple columns. I've seen it done before but not sure how to go about creating it. I have information starting in B2:B100, to J2:J100 and need to have everything together in column A separated by a "_" corresponding with each individual line from A2:A100.

The data inbetween B2:J100 change frequently and that's why I would like to have it as a button instead of just Concatenate function and dragging all the way down. Just looking for something that looks cleaner.

Any help would be great!

-Maykid

Comment: Just put `=B2&"_"&J2` in cell `A2` and drag down. There's no need for VBA here. This will be dynamic and adjust accordingly as your values in column B and J change.

Comment: If your data looks like a data table, *make it* a data table. Click "Format as table" from the "Home" Ribbon, and enter the formula *once* and enjoy Excel automatically filling the whole entire table column with it, and automatically filling it for any new row that will be added in the future.

Comment: I know you don't want to drag a formula but If you have Excel 2016 you can use the function `TEXTJOIN` you can select easily the delimitator, if you want to consider blanks cells or not, and specify a range. `=TEXTJOIN("-",1,B2:J2)`

Comment: Are you joining just two columns or all the columns between B and J inclusive?

Comment: @QHarr I'm joining all columns from B - J, but also want to make it so if lets say someone forgot to enter in Column D or E, it leaves cell A blank but continues onto the next row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to concatenate ignoring blank cells you could do something like this.

```
Dim temp As String
For Row = 2 To 100
    temp = ""
    For col = 2 To 10
        If Cells(Row, col) <> "" Then
            If temp <> "" Then temp = temp & "_"              
            temp = temp & Cells(Row, col)
        End If
    Next col

    Cells(Row, 1) = temp
Next Row
```

**Update**2: If you want to totally ignore any rows containing blank fields use an else statement.

```
Dim temp As String
For Row = 2 To 100
    temp = ""
    For col = 2 To 4
        If Cells(Row, col) <> "" Then
            If temp <> "" Then temp = temp & "_"
            temp = temp & Cells(Row, col)
        Else
            temp = ""
            Exit For
        End If
    Next col

    Cells(Row, 1) = temp
Next Row
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the formula break if there is a empty cell in Column C? For example rows 2-6 are all filled, but line 7 is missing 1 cell and 8-14 are all filled, is it possible to make line 7 not fill in any data?

Answer (score 2):

But if you *really* need a VBA solution, that would be this:

```
Sub Test()

For i = 2 To 100
    Range("A" & i).Value = Range("B" & i).Value & "_" & Range("J" & i).Value
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: With this, lets say in columns C & D if I needed to concatenate these later on would I just add to the formula so, `Range("C" & i).Value` and so on?
Also is there a way to not have the `"_"` in blank cells that don't have information in Column A?

Comment: @Maykid if you don't want the `"_"`, don't concatenate the `"_"`. If the `"_"` concatenation needs to be conditional, make it conditional. `If Range("J" & i).Value = "" Then...`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test()
    Dim iRow As Long

    For iRow = 2 To 100 
        With Range("B:J").Rows(iRow)
            If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells)>0 Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "|"
            Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Replace(Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Value)),"_"), "_|_","")
            .Replace what:="|", Replacement:= "", LookAt:=xlWhole
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```